# 1.9 - Add custom image upload to CMS Page - Won't save

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, image-upload

I have an observer here:

```
app/code/local/LCMS/CMS/Model/Observer.php
```

Which contains the following:

```
class LCMS_CMS_Model_Observer
{
    public function cmsField($observer)
    {

        $model = Mage::registry('cms_page');

        $form = $observer->getForm();
        $form->setEnctype("multipart/form-data");

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('lcms_author_fieldset', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('cms')->__('Additional'),'class'=>'fieldset-wide'));

        $fieldset->addField('ogimg', 'image', array(
          'name'      => 'ogimg',
          'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('OG Image'),
          'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('OG Image'),
          'disabled'  => false,
          'value'    => $model->getogimg()
        ));

    }
}
```

This gives me an 'additional' section on the CMS Page admin, with a file select:

[image: File select screenshot]

It allows me to select a file, however it doesn't actually save it.

[image: File selected]

How can I get this file to upload/save?

Comment: Please check getter `$model->getogimg()` ... think it it should be `$model->getOgimg()`

Comment: `$model->getOgimg()` still doesn't save the image for me unfortunately

Comment: This only creates field, you have to make function for it

Comment: Where do I make the function? Is there a guide anywhere? I have tried to follow a few tutorials but they don't seem to work

Comment: Kindly follow this [link](https://goweb.vn/kien-thuc-web-vi/thiet-ke-web/magento-add-custom-field-to-cms-page-929.html)

Comment: Thanks! Have you managed to get that link to work? I get the following error: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in Cms.php on line 3`